# Need reference of books which deals with ideal theory of tensor product

Tags: reference-request, c-star-algebras, ideals

> Is there any book which deals with Ideal theory of tensor product of $C^{\ast}-$ algebras

Comment: Is there an "ideal theory" of C*-algebras? Doesn't seem like much can be said in general.

Comment: @NikWeaver: I was looking for a book which discusses for instance ideals of min, max or projective tensor product?

Comment: In the textbook by Brown-Ozawa, Corollary 9.4.6 shows that two-sided closed ideals in the spatial tensor product $A \otimes B$ are generated by tensor products of two-sided closed ideals, provided $A$ or $B$ is exact. Consequently, $Prime(A\otimes B) \cong Prime(A) \times Prime(B)$ if $A$ or $B$ is exact, where $Prime(-)$ is the prime ideal space (the space of prime ideals with the hull-kernel topology). Also, Section 2.8 of the Blanchard-Kirchberg JFA 2004 paper deals with the ideal structure of spatial tensor products, even if none of the $C^\ast$-algebras are exact.

Comment: @JamieGabe: I will have a look. Thank you.